# Translate Java string signing to OpenSSL

Tags: java, openssl

For a payment API I need to hash a string (a request payload) with SHA-512,
sign itwith "RSA" according to the documentation.

> 1. Hash the payload string (payout instruction) using SHA512 algorithm.
> 2. Sign the hashed payload string using RSA algorithm and the signing certificate private key.
> 3. Base64 encode the signed hash

Step 1 and 3 I've got no problems with. Step 2 is the problem. Support sent me a java example but we don't run java and I would like to do this in OpenSSL if at all possible.

```
private static String createSignature(String stringToBeSigned, PrivateKey privateKey) {
    try {
        byte[] hashString = hashString(stringToBeSigned);

        Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA512withRSA");
        sign.initSign(privateKey);
        sign.update(hashString);

        byte[] signature = sign.sign();
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not create signed payout request.", e);
    }
}


private static byte[] hashString(String stringToBeHashed) {
    try {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        return digest.digest(stringToBeHashed.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The Key is provided. How do I find what "SHA512withRSA" corresponds to using OpenSSL?

Comment: Just run this on command line: "openssl dgst -sha512 -sign privatekey2048.pem -out rsamessage.signature.bin rsamessage.txt". In the second step you need Base64 encode the "rsamessage.signature.bin" file to the requested text encoding.

Comment: That Java code is actually hashing _twice_, once explicitly and once inside the signature algorithm (which is standard; the RSA signatures commonly used, and implemented by Java, namely PKCS1-v1.5 and PSS, _include_ hashing) -- is that really what the API wants? If so, `openssl sha512 -binary <data | openssl sha512 -sign privateRSA.pem | openssl base64 -A` . Your data must already be UTF8; OpenSSL doesn't encode or decode data (well, it _can_ do de/compression, but nowadays people remove that because CRIME etc) (@MichaelFehr)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Do you mean "privateRSA.key"? Using the key-file I get "Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY". I have a .key, a .pem and a .p12.

Comment: I mean 'a file that contains the RSA private key in a PEM format (supported by OpenSSL)'. I have no knowledge what is in your files. People _typically_ use suffix .key for a privatekey, but you'll have to look in yours to see if it is, and whether it's PEM (and which). People use .pem for many things, but it should be _something_ in PEM and you can tell what by looking at it. Similarly .p12 usually means a PKCS12 file, which is _not_ specifically a privatekey (although it may _contain_ one) and is never in PEM, thus unsuitable for this command.